# Solving for quartile and decile using Python

Tags: python, statistics

Is there a library for Python 2.7 that can solve quartiles and deciles. It seems that numpy doesn't have any functions for it. Can you give me a link if there are any. Thanks in advance! :D

Comment: You could use numpy.percentile to get quartiles and deciles. http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.percentile.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using [np.percentile](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.percentile.html), you could try something like

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> var = np.array([10, 7, 4, 3, 2, 1]) # input array
>>> np.percentile(var, np.arange(25, 100, 25)) # quartiles
array([2.25, 3.5 , 6.25])
>>> np.percentile(var, np.arange(10, 100, 10)) # deciles
array([1.5,  2. ,  2.5,  3. ,  3.5,  4. ,  5.5,  7. ,  8.5])
```

Comment: Also worth checking out `pandas.qcut`, which will split your array up into whatever quantiles you specify.

Comment: That seems incorrect to me. There should be 3 quartiles (i.e. 25%, 50%, 75%) and 9 deciles (i.e. 10%, 20%, ..., 90%). Here the first value of both is the minimum because you start `np.arange` at 0 use instead: `np.percentile(var, np.arange(25, 100, 25)) # quartiles` and `np.percentile(var, np.arange(10, 100, 10)) # deciles`